# ios8 iPad splitview view issue

Tags: ios8, ipad

> I am trying to ran my ios app using xcode 6 with ios8. On iOS8 ipad
>   splitview(basically master and detail screen) not rendering properly
>   but in ios7 it was able to render properly without any issues. The
>   issue was the maser view moved bit left since am seeing some unknown
>   images on right hand side of the master table view. This happens when i do change the orientation from portrait to landscape and vice verse.

Any idea how to fix this on ios8 ipad splitview?. For more info attaching screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this code in `UITableViewController` (or higher in hierarchy)

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Change the `[UIColor whiteColor]` to the color you want to replace the `green` with.

Setting background color for cell or content view in storyboard in Xcode does not solve the problem.
This problem occurs only on iPad under iOS 7.1.2 & 8.1 (i use these versions) and does not occur on iPhone (4S with iOS 8.1, 5S with 7.1.2, 6 with 8.1).
May be it happened in combination of Xcode 6.1 iOS 8.1 SDK and `UISplitViewController`.